# How to set a svg file in typescript class?

Tags: angular, typescript, svg

I have an "element" class with an svg file. Depending on the type of element, svg uses different graphics.

```
<svg:g *ngFor="let element of elements">

    <g *ngIf="element.type == 0">
      <rect class="elem_back" x="-15" y="-15" width="35" height="40" stroke-opacity="1"></rect>
      <circle r="10" fill="none" ></circle>
      <circle r="10" fill="none" cx="5" cy="5" ></circle>
      <circle r="10" fill="none" cx="0" cy="10" ></circle>
    </g>

    <g *ngIf="element.type == 1">
      <rect class="elem_back" x="-5" y="-15" width="30" height="50" stroke-opacity="1"></rect>
      <line x1="10" y1="-10" x2="10" y2="0"></line>
      <line  x1="10" y1="20" x2="10" y2="30"></line>
      <rect width="20" height="20"  fill="none"></rect>
    </g>

    <g *ngIf="element.type == 2">
      <rect class="elem_back" x="-15" y="-5" width="25" height="40" stroke-opacity="1"></rect>
      <line  x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="10"></line>
      <line x1="0" y1="10" x2="-10" y2="20"></line>
      <line  x1="0" y1="20" x2="0" y2="30"></line>
    </g>

</svg:g>
```

But I think, it is not correct, we should have svg graphics in separate files. Do we have the possibility to create a setter method for svg file to each element? Something like in .ts file:

```
if (elements[i].type === 0){
   elements[i].svg = svg('svgForType0.svg')
} else if (elements[i].type === 1){
   elements[i].svg = svg('svgForType1.svg')
}...
```

Comment: Try using ViewChild - or ViewChildren in your case. In the ngFor, use an ng-container with #someName and query it from your class. Just remember to do this in after content init lifecycle.

Comment: Dont you think you can use an img tag and use the svg in src and then change the src based on your condition?

Comment: its a very bad practice, create separate svgs and based condition show/hide the svg